# Use REGEX_SUBSTR to get all characters before certain delimiter

Tags: sql, string, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to parse `2021-11-16T04:42:00.000+0000` into `2021-11-16` using REGEX_SUBSTR through SQL on the Snowflake platform.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: tried to reference `REGEXP_SUBSTR("Website", '^(https?://)?(.*)', 1, 1, 'e', 2) ` which would get me a domain after the https portion of an URL - so something like `REGEXP_SUBSTR("TimeStamp", '^(T)?(.*)', 1, 1, 'e', 2)` - which obviously did not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select left('2021-11-16T04:42:00.000+0000', 10);
```

output

```
2021-11-16
```

Comment: *face palm* thanks for this ... guess regex_substr was overkill

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to achieve:

```
with t as (
    select '2021-11-16T04:42:00.000+0000' a
    union 
    select 'garbage' a
)
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(a, '[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}') as date
from t;

+------------+
| DATE       |
|------------|
| 2021-11-16 |
| NULL       |
+------------+
```

OR

```
with t as (
    select '2021-11-16T04:42:00.000+0000' a
    union 
    select 'garbage' a
)
select try_to_timestamp(a, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH12:MI:SS.FFTZHTZM')::date as date
from t;

+------------+
| DATE       |
|------------|
| 2021-11-16 |
| NULL       |
+------------+
```

OR

```
with t as (
    select '2021-11-16T04:42:00.000+0000' a
    union 
    select 'garbage' a
)
select left(a, 10) as date
from t;

+------------+
| DATE       |
|------------|
| 2021-11-16 |
| garbage    |
+------------+
```